# How to import Mongo Libraries in Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, maven

I used mongo-java-driver version 3.7.1 & 3.8.2 in java build path. Still, I am getting the error "the import com.mongo.MongoClient cannot be resolved".

**Connection.class**

```
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.Db;

public class MongoClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
            System.out.println("connection successfully established");
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this error during the build. If so is this a build from an IDE or mavenized or something manual? To resolve the duplicate dependency you can choose to exclude one in maven. But having 2 is generally speaking a bad idea.

Comment: I import it this way with `mongodb-driver-sync 3.8` : `import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;` and
`import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;`, does it solve the import for you ?

Comment: there two methods are not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MongoDB Java sample](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/), you can start building this way :

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MongoClass {

private MongoDatabase database = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("username", "database", "password".toCharArray());

    MongoClientSettings.Builder builder = MongoClientSettings.builder();

    builder.applicationName("myapp");

    builder.credential(credential);

    builder.applyToClusterSettings((b) ->
            b.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017))));

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(builder.build());

    database = mongoClient.getDatabase("MYDATABASE_1");

    mongoClient.close();
}
```